# excel countif with user input variables

Tags: excel, vba, countif

new to VBA so please be gentle.....

I have a script that check for duplicates and inserts a count in a column, this works fine however the sheets are often different so I need to ask the user which column to check for duplicates and which column to insert the count. I've modified the script, but I'm only getting zero's entered into the destination column. I can't see what's going wrong. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

```
Sub LookForDuplicates()

Dim LastRow As Long

Dim column1 As String
'display an input box asking for column
column1 = InputBox( _
"Please enter column to ckeck")
'if no file name chosen, say so and stop
If Len(column1) = 0 Then
MsgBox "No column entered"

Exit Sub
End If

Dim column2 As String
'display an input box asking for column
column2 = InputBox( _
"Please enter column to insert results")
'if no file name chosen, say so and stop
If Len(column2) = 0 Then
MsgBox "No column entered"

Exit Sub
End If

'-------------------------------------------------------
```

'This is the original version of my script with set columns which works great..... However I need the user to specify the column to checck and also which column the results will be entered.

```
  'LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  '   With Range("E1")
  '  .FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(C2,RC[-3])"
  '  .AutoFill Destination:=Range("E1:E" & LastRow)
  '   Range("E1").Select
  '  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Duplicates"
'-----------------------------------------------------   
LastRow = Range(column1 & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 With Range(column2 & "1")
.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(C2,RC[-3])"
.AutoFill Destination:=Range(column2 & "1" & ":" & column2 & LastRow)
 Range(column2 & "1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Duplicates"

  End With
End Sub
```

I cannot get this working with the user input variables, apologies if I'm missing something but I can't find any resources on this....

The formula: =COUNTIF($B:$B,B2) works except when in the macro.

I need to add this line to the macro replaced with variables from user input like: =COUNTIF($column1:$column1,column12) but I keep getting syntax errors.

Thanks.

Comment: I have updated the answer with your comments. Please take a look at it. I used `range` as it's much flexible compared to a string that would represent the range/cell.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution if anybody else might find this useful:

The issue was even though column 1 was entered as a Column Reference H for example the COUNTIF function required this as a numeric reference so added an extra variable on the column1 value to the numeric value and modified the formula to suit. All working now:

```
Dim LastRow As Long

Dim column1 As String
'display an input box asking for column
column1 = InputBox( _
"Please enter column to ckeck")
'if no file name chosen, say so and stop
ColumnNumber = Columns(column1).Column

If Len(column1) = 0 Then
MsgBox "No column entered"


Exit Sub
End If

Dim column2 As String
'display an input box asking for column
column2 = InputBox( _
"Please enter column to insert results")
'if no file name chosen, say so and stop
If Len(column2) = 0 Then
MsgBox "No column entered"

Exit Sub
End If

LastRow = Range(column1 & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     With Range(column2 & "1")
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(C" & ColumnNumber & ",C" & ColumnNumber & ")"
    .AutoFill Destination:=Range(column2 & "1" & ":" & column2 & LastRow)
     Range(column2 & "1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Duplicates"

  End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting a `String`/Text value from your input box then you should specify it,

```
Dim column1 As String
'display an input box asking for column
column1 = InputBox("Please enter column to ckeck", "Range to Check", , , , 2)
```

Instead of juggling with a String here, why don't you just use the `Range` object where user can simply click on either full range or one cell in that column you want to check..

Using a range to get the inputbox data: You main issue seems to be setting range to check column in formula.

```
Option Explicit

Sub LookForDuplicates()
    Dim LastRow As Long, StartRow as Long
    Dim column1 As Range, column2 As Range

    Set column1 = Application.InputBox("Please enter _ 
            column to ckeck", "Range to Check", , , , , , 8)
    If column1 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No column entered"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set column2 = Application.InputBox("Please _ 
                  enter column to insert results", _
                              "Range to Output Results", , , , , , 8)
    If column2 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No column entered"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, column1.Column).End(xlUp).Row '--updated here
    StartRow = column2.Row '-- here a new code added, assuming that you will have at least one row for column titles 
     With column2
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(R" & column1.Row _ 
                & "C[-1]:R" & LastRow + 2 & "C[-1],RC[-1])"
        .AutoFill Destination:=column2.Resize(LastRow - StartRow, 1)
    End With
    column2.Offset(-1, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "Duplicates"
End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @bonCodigo I really appreciate you taking the time to help however a range is not really suitable for this. The columns are often very long and the users will struggle with this. I really need to specify a column to check and a column for output.

Comment: In the above sample, **you don't have to select the entire column range**. First cell is enough and that's what I have done above. Then the code is finding the last used row (`LastRow = column1.Rows.Count`)in that column instead of you going to search via the entire column and which is a performance matter. I am not sure if you really got what I meant in the above code. Please let me know :)

Comment: Ah yes that makes more sense. I was under the impression you had to select the entire data selection. Thanks so much for your help it is really appreciated. Now if I run that script and select a column of data and then another column to enter the data I get an error 1004 Apllication-defined or object -defined error on line:  .FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(R" & column1.Row & "C[-1]:R" & LastRow + 2 & "C[-1],RC[-1])" I took the _ and new line out just incase....

Comment: sorry but I can't get this working, does the exact code work for you? Perhaps we have different versions of excel would this cause it? Thanks again.

Comment: @Paul if the exact code is not working I would NOT POST, or add an output screen image :) Plus then I would mark it as *untested*. This code works for me. Are your macros enabled. What do you mean in your comment? *I took the _ and new line out just incase....*?

Comment: sorry I hope I didn't come across wrong then, I am very grateful for your assistance and just wondered if maybe it was my excel version or something. I was just confirming as it wouldn't work. Yes macro's are enabled it runs, I select a column by clicking in it, then I click in the column for the results and it offers to debug. I've just been trying and if I select a column and then select the correct amount of cells to output into it works but not if you select the column. Thanks very much.

Comment: @Paul My apology I was so sure that I have copied the code I tested out as you can see the output results. It seems I have made a mistake :( very sorry. Just updated it. I am keeping the same workbook open and adding multiple sheets and modules. Please take give it a shot. :)

Comment: Hey no problem, I just really appreciate your help. Can you tell me exactly how you use it. When I run it I am getting mixed results depending on where I click. It mainly works if I select the top row containing my header but I have to then select the row next to it, any other row does not work. Most of the time it stops at the last but one line: column2.Offset(-1, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "Duplicates" Thanks again. I'm sure I'm just using it incorrectly.....